# react-router V6.10 "url changes but component does not render!"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Despite checking all the answers already posted on stack overflow, I coudn't find the solution for my case!

i've used  element in header component to access other pages. by clicking to this links, url changes but the component doesn't render!
by refreshing page, the component will render properly.

**this problem only occure on *course page* which use dynamic url! (on other components like *HomePage* link works properly and only on ***course pages*** this issue exists!)

here's my codes

*App.tsx*

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<HomePage />} path="/"></Route>
        <Route element={<CourseCategory />} path="/course-category"></Route>

        {/* the problem occurs on this component */}
        <Route element={<CourseDetails />} path="/course/:courseShortName"></Route>

        <Route element={<Article />} path="/article"></Route>
        <Route element={<LoginPage />} path="/login"></Route>
        <Route element={<RegisterPage />} path="/register"></Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

*Header.tsx*

```
<Link to="/course/css" > title </Link>
```

*CourseDetails.tsx*

```
const { courseShortName } = useParams();

{/* this function fetch data to show */}
fetchSelectedCourse({ courseShortName })
```

**The issue:** when I click on one of the links (only on course page!), the url changes to the corresponding path but the component doesn't render. so I have to refresh the page to actually make it appear!

Comment: what is the value when you `console.log(courseShortName)` in "CourseDetails.tsx"?

Comment: We can't address issues in code we can't see. Please [edit] the post to include all relevant code you are working with as part of a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finaly I've found the problem! this happened becauese in < CourseDetails /> compponent i should used **useEffect()** to monitor **useParams()** changes!

*CourseDetais.tsx*

```
    useEffect(() => {
    fetchSelectedCourse(courseShortName);
}, [courseShortName]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your router setup is a bit unorthodox, it may appear to work but it's not idiomatic which results in the strange behaviours you're experiencing. Here's an idiomatic approach to your routing:

```
import {
  Routes,
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Link,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";

function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Page />} path="/">
          <Route element={<HomePage />} path="" />
          <Route element={<CourseCategory />} path="course-category"></Route>
          {/* the problem occurs on this component */}
          <Route element={<CourseDetails />} path="course/:courseShortName" />
          <Route element={<Article />} path="article" />
          <Route element={<LoginPage />} path="login" />
          <Route element={<RegisterPage />} path="register" />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-architecture-uvcg3j?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: The question isn't about code/route structure or organization. While useful information this answer doesn't address the issue OP is asking for help with.